How to call a binary with execFile() multiple times in parallel?
I'm using execFile and execFileSync to invoke a CLI tool called rad from inside my Node.js app. Specifically, I need to call it once to retrieve a list of "Patch" IDs in a "Repo" and once more for each of those IDs to retrieve the full Patch entity with that ID.
A Repo can contain hundreds or thousands of such patches so I want to parallelize retrieving those full entities.
A shell command imitating what I want to do takes ~1s to run for my use case. Here it is as an example:
rad cob list --repo $(rad .) --type xyz.radicle.patch | xargs -n 1 -P 0 -I {} rad cob show --repo $(rad .) --type xyz.radicle.patch --object {}

Unfortunately, despite my best efforts to parallelize the FileSync calls, my code seems to run for at least 10 times longer than the shell script I used as control, and after profiling the execution it's clearly visible on the flamegraph those calls are not running in parallel.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong and how to achieve truly parallel execution of the rad binary, ideally without spawning a shell and by not having more invocations running in parallel than the count of CPU cores on the user's machine.
resolveConcurrently() is the main function trying to do the parallelization:
async function resolveConcurrently<T>(
  jobs: (() => Promise<T>)[],
  maxConcurrentJobs?: number,
): Promise<T[]> {
  const results: T[] = []
  const pending = new Set<Promise<void>>()
  const limit =
    maxConcurrentJobs && maxConcurrentJobs > 0
      ? maxConcurrentJobs
      : Math.ceil(cpus().length * 0.85)

  for (const job of jobs) {
    const promise = job()
      .then((result) => {
        results.push(result)
        pending.delete(promise)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(`Error executing promise: ${(error as Error).message}`)
        pending.delete(promise)
      })

    pending.add(promise)
    if (pending.size >= limit) {
      await Promise.race(pending)
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)) // Without this Node.js crashes
    }
  }

  await Promise.all(pending)

  return results
}

The above is called by retrieveAllPatches() like so:
import { cpus } from 'node:os'
import { execRad, execRadAsync } from './exec'

export async function retrieveAllPatches(rid: Repository['id']) {
  const patchIds = retrieveAllPatchIds(rid)

  const patchResolvers = patchIds.map(
    (patchId) => async () => await retrieveOnePatch(patchId, rid),
  )

  const patches = await resolveConcurrently(patchResolvers)

  return patches
}

async function retrieveOnePatch(
  patchId: Patch['id'],
  rid: Repository['id'],
): Promise<Patch | undefined> {
  const { stdout: stringifiedPatch } = await execRadAsync([
    'cob',
    'show',
    '--repo',
    rid,
    '--type',
    'xyz.radicle.patch',
    '--object',
    patchId,
  ])
  if (stringifiedPatch) {
    const parsedPatch = JSON.parse(stringifiedPatch) as CobPatch
    const patch = transformCobPatch(parsedPatch)

    return patch
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Error retrieving details for patch ${patchId}`)
  }
}

function retrieveAllPatchIds(rid: Repository['id']): Patch['id'][] {
  const { stdout: patchIds } = execRad([
    'cob',
    'list',
    '--repo',
    rid,
    '--type',
    'xyz.radicle.patch',
  ])
  if (patchIds) {
    return patchIds.trim().split('\n')
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Error retrieving patch ids`)
  }
}

Here's also execRad() and my rough implementation of an execRadAsync() each using execFileSync() and execFile() resepectively from node:child_process.
export function execRad(
  args: string[] = [],
  options?: {
    shouldLog?: boolean
    timeout?: number
    cwd?: (string & {}) | '$workspaceDir' // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    env?: ExecFileSyncOptionsWithStringEncoding['env']
  },
): XOR<{ stdout: string }, { errorCode: string | number; stdout?: string; stderr?: string }> {
  const opts = options ?? {}

  const truncatedRadCmd = `rad ${args
    .map((arg) => maybeEscapeArg(truncateKeepWords(arg, 40, ' […]')))
    .join(' ')}`

  try {
    let cwd: string | undefined
    if (opts.cwd === '$workspaceDir') {
      const firstWorkspaceDir = getWorkspaceFolderPaths()?.[0] // Hack: always use only 0th folder
      if (!firstWorkspaceDir) {
        throw new Error(
          `Failed resolving path of workspace directory in order to exec "${truncatedRadCmd}" in it`,
        )
      }
      cwd = firstWorkspaceDir
    } else {
      cwd = opts.cwd
    }

    const configPathToNodeHome = getConfig('radicle.advanced.pathToNodeHome')
    const spawnOpts: ExecFileSyncOptionsWithStringEncoding = {
      shell: false,
      cwd,
      timeout: opts.timeout ?? 30_000,
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      env: {
        ...process.env,
        ...(configPathToNodeHome ? { RAD_HOME: configPathToNodeHome } : {}),
        ...opts.env,
      },
    }

    const stdout = execFileSync(
      useEnvStore().resolvedAbsolutePathToRadBinary,
      args,
      spawnOpts,
    ).trim()
    if (opts.shouldLog ?? false) {
      log(stdout, 'info', truncatedRadCmd)
    }

    return { stdout }
  } catch (err) {
    const error = err as Error & {
      status: number // should be non-zero as per the process-return-value convention
      code?: string // set if spawning child process failed: 'ENOENT', 'ETIMEDOUT'
      stdout?: string
      stderr?: string
    }

    console.error(truncatedRadCmd, '\n\n', error)
    if (opts.shouldLog ?? false) {
      log(
        error.stdout?.trim() ||
          error.message.trim() ||
          error.stderr?.trim() ||
          `Failed executing command: ${truncatedRadCmd}`,
        'error',
        truncatedRadCmd,
      )
    }

    // will show up only in the Debug console during development
    return {
      stdout: error.stdout?.trim(),
      stderr: error.stderr?.trim(),
      errorCode: error.code || error.status,
    }
  }
}

export async function execRadAsync(
  args: string[] = [],
  options?: {
    shouldLog?: boolean
    timeout?: number
    cwd?: (string & {}) | '$workspaceDir' // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
    env?: ExecFileOptionsWithStringEncoding['env']
  },
): Promise<
  XOR<{ stdout: string }, { errorCode: string | number; stdout?: string; stderr?: string }>
> {
  const opts = options ?? {}

  const truncatedRadCmd = `rad ${args
    .map((arg) => maybeEscapeArg(truncateKeepWords(arg, 40, ' […]')))
    .join(' ')}`

  let cwd: string | undefined
  if (opts.cwd === '$workspaceDir') {
    const firstWorkspaceDir = getWorkspaceFolderPaths()?.[0] // Hack: always use only 0th folder
    if (!firstWorkspaceDir) {
      throw new Error(
        `Failed resolving path of workspace directory in order to exec "${truncatedRadCmd}" in it`,
      )
    }
    cwd = firstWorkspaceDir
  } else {
    cwd = opts.cwd
  }

  const configPathToNodeHome = getConfig('radicle.advanced.pathToNodeHome')
  const spawnOpts: ExecFileOptionsWithStringEncoding = {
    shell: false,
    cwd,
    timeout: opts.timeout ?? 30_000,
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    env: {
      ...process.env,
      ...(configPathToNodeHome ? { RAD_HOME: configPathToNodeHome } : {}),
      ...opts.env,
    },
  }

  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    execFile(
      useEnvStore().resolvedAbsolutePathToRadBinary,
      args,
      spawnOpts,
      (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
          console.error(truncatedRadCmd, '\n\n', error)
          if (opts.shouldLog ?? false) {
            log(
              stdout.trim() ||
                error.message.trim() ||
                stderr.trim() ||
                `Failed executing command: ${truncatedRadCmd}`,
              'error',
              truncatedRadCmd,
            )
          }
          resolve({
            errorCode: error.code || error.errno || error.message.trim(),
            stderr: stderr.trim(),
          })
        } else {
          if (opts.shouldLog ?? false) {
            log(stdout, 'info', truncatedRadCmd)
          }
          resolve({ stdout: stdout.trim() })
        }
      },
    )
  })
}

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, perhaps regarding the event loop or Node's child_process lib.

There's a lot of excess stuff here. Can you create a minimal example of what you're having trouble with.

Problem
The issue seems to be within your resolveConcurrently function. It receives an array of promises as an argument and iterates over it, creating custom handlers with then / catch. Here's a breakdown of what is happening within for/loop:

You create async wrapper. When wrapper successfully resolves a promise, appending results list and removing itself from the pending list.
You put your wrapper into the pending list
You check if pending list is too large compared to given limit parameter. If it is, you wait for a single promise within your stack and then proceed to the next element in a jobs list.

So what's the problem? Promise.race is designed to return the first resolved promise from the list. In your case, you just wait when at least promise to resolve in order to proceed.
Say, you've got a limit of 2 concurrent promises, but have 10 promises, which need to be handled. So it goes like this:

Push first promise into the pending list
Push second promise into the pending list
Push third promise into the pending list. At this point the pending list is too large, so you wait for at least one of pending promises to resolve. Only after that you proceed to the next job. And it goes like this for the rest of for loop.

So for limit of 2 you concurrently handle only 2 first promises, the rest goes synchronously.
Custom solution (not recommended)
So, to pool new jobs without awaiting for the old ones, I created a separate generator function and used it in resolveConcurrently:
async function resolveConcurrently(
    jobs,
    maxConcurrentJobs,
  ) {
    const limit =
      maxConcurrentJobs && maxConcurrentJobs > 0
        ? maxConcurrentJobs
        : Math.ceil(cpus().length * 0.85)
  
    return Promise.all(getJobsWithLimit(jobs, limit));
  }

Pretty straightforward so far, but things are a bit more complicated in getJobsWithLimit generator function. There jobs, which are actively executing are kept in a pending list. When there are too many pending jobs (n < limit), rest of the jobs are kept in a separate queue. For loop can be described as:

Create async wrapper. On resolve / reject, promise removes itself from pending list. Also it picks next job from queue and puts it in pending has available slots (size < limit).
If pending has free slots - put wrapper in pending
If pending has no free slots - put wrapper in queue.

The rest is pretty much the same, and the code is given below:
function* getIterator (jobs, limit) {
    const pending = [];
    const nextInQueue = [];

    const handleFinishedPromise = (promise) => {
        // Return promise from the pending list
        pending.filter((pendingPromise) => pendingPromise !== promise);
        // Move next job from nextInQueue to pending if appropriate
        if (pending.size <= limit) {
            const nextPromise = nextInQueue.shift();
            if (nextPromise) pending.add(nextPromise);
        }
    }
  
    // Fill pending and nextInQueue with values
    for (const job of jobs) {
      const promise = job()
        .then((result) => {
          handleFinishedPromise();
          return result;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(`Error executing promise: ${(error).message}`)
          handleFinishedPromise();
        })
  
      // Already filled pending limit
      if (pending.length >= limit) {
        nextInQueue.push(promise);
      } else {
        pending.push(promise)
      }
    }

    while (pending.length > 0) {
        yield pending.shift();
    }
};

Also notice that in the provided example there are no sets, only lists. Given concurrent execution, it's safer to immediately mutate the list retrieving an element, as opposed to checking size, retrieving an element and removing the corresponding index afterwards.
Solution with 3rd party library (recommended)
Even though sample code above is working, I strongly recommend getting a third party library for limiting concurrent promises. P-limit is a simple, lightweight and a popular (116 millions weekly downloads at the moment) library, which does just that. Here's the idea how you can use it in your case:
async function resolveConcurrently(
  jobs,
  maxConcurrentJobs,
) {
  const limit =
    maxConcurrentJobs && maxConcurrentJobs > 0
      ? maxConcurrentJobs
      : Math.ceil(cpus().length * 0.85)

  const wrapper = pLimit(limit);

  return Promise.all(jobs.map(wrapper));
}

